# Is there a way to simulate tombstoning on the windows phone 7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

One of the requirements for a Windows Phone 7 application that I am writing is to handle the app going into standby and back when something interrupts it (e.g. a phone call). This is called "tombstoning" an application. Is there a way to simulate this behavior on the emulator? It will be fairly difficult to test unless we can either do this or get an actual phone (the latter of which is a trifle difficult).

Comment: dont forget the difference between Tombstoning and Deactivation: this is a really useful article to read for anyone interested in the subject (which, if you're building a WP7 app, you really should be) - http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/16/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simulate tombstoning by simply pushing (clicking) on the start or search "hardware" buttons on the emulator. This will cause your app to be "tombstoned".

There is no way to simulate incoming calls, etc. on the emulator.

Comment: And as soon as one of those two buttons have been pushed, the "hardware" back button will un-tombstone the app.

Comment: With 7.1 this doesn't work anymore since the app is going into the new dormant state instead of being tombstoned right away. But there is a new option in the debug properties "Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging" which works great.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these two topic sections for details on what Matt/Amenti describe:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff806372(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Toforceanapplicationstatechangefordebuggingpurposes

and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff806372(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Toforceanapplicationstatechangefordebuggingpurposes